# Using VC++ MFC dialogue to retrieve data from a database

Tags: c#, c++, mfc

I wrote the code below to retrieve data from a database using C# Windows Form Application, but now I would like to implement the same idea of Data retrieval in VC++ MFC dialogue control: This is the code i implemented in C# Windows Form Application: Please kindly help

```
c.Open();
DateTime startDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
DateTime endDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox2.Text);
string query = "SELECT * FROM People_Tracking WHERE Enter_Exit_Time BETWEEN @startDateTime AND @endDateTime ;";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, c);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@startDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDateTime;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@endDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDateTime;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable t = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(t);
dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
```

This is the image of how I want to display it in VC++ MFC dialogue control:
[image]

Comment: What is the problem you have? Where is your actual MFC code?

Comment: @JamesZ . My problem is how can I do the same in MFC. I am totally new in using MFC. How you help?

Answer (score 6):

MFC has support for ODBC with `CDatabase` and `CRecordset`

[Open Database Connectivity (ODBC)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ds2ktb.aspx)

To create the database:

```
SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_ADD_DSN,
    L"MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)",
    L"DSN=DataBaseName\0CREATE_DB=C:\\PATH\\DB.mdb\0\0");
//in this example "c:\\Path" must exist
```

To open the database:

```
CDatabase db;
db.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE,
    L"ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\PATH\\DB.mdb");
```

Example of SQL commands:

```
db.ExecuteSQL(L"CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (ID TEXT(4), NAME TEXT(10))");
db.ExecuteSQL(L"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, NAME) values('1000', 'MyName')");
```

Reading data using `CRecordset`

```
try
{
    CDatabase db;
    db.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE,
        L"ODBC;DRIVER={MICROSOFT ACCESS DRIVER (*.mdb)};DBQ=c:\\PATH\\DB.mdb");

    CRecordset records(&db);
    records.Open(CRecordset::forwardOnly, L"SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE", CRecordset::readOnly);

    while (!records.IsEOF())
    {
        CString id, name;
        records.GetFieldValue(L"ID", id);
        records.GetFieldValue(L"NAME", name);

        //int index = m_listCtrl.InsertItem(0, id, 0);
        //m_listCtrl.SetItemText(index, 1, name);
        TRACE(L"ID = %s, Name = %s\n", id, name);

        records.MoveNext();
    }
    db.Close();
}
catch (CDBException *e)
{
    MessageBox(L"DB error: " + e->m_strError);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I did you you suggested, but the program is indicating one error in following line of code: Saying - identifier "m_listCtrl" is undefine 

int index = m_listCtrl.InsertItem(0, Enter_Exit_Time, 0);

Comment: It assumes you have the following declaration in your dialog class: `CListCtrl m_listCtrl;` That's 2 different issues about `CListCtrl` and database, you can't learn both of them at the same time. For this example comment out `m_listCtrl` and use `TRACE` or `MessageBox` to test the database (see edit)